# Oracle procedure all input variables to be set in upper case

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a scenario where I need to convert all input parameter for a Oracle SP to upper case before processing:-

```
procedure Name (
v_Param1 in number,
v_Param2 IN varchar2,
v_Para3 IN VARCHAr2,
v_Param4 IN VARCHAr2,
v_MID IN VARCHAr2)
```

The inputs can be of lower, upper or camel case but I need to match it with records in table with uppercase, which is a costly operation at database end in recursive calls.
Is there a way I can convert these values before hand at once so the input parameters are converted at uppercase.

Comment: @AnkurPatel: that is not the manual for the Oracle database. That is the manual for the JavaDB (aka Derby)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare and set new variables:

```
procedure Name ( v_Param1 in number, v_Param2 IN varchar2, v_Para3 IN VARCHAr2, v_Param4 IN VARCHAr2, v_MID IN VARCHAr2
               )
as
    v_param2_upper varchar2(4000);
    v_param3_upper varchar2(4000);
    v_param4_upper varchar2(4000);
    v_param5_upper varchar2(4000);
begin
    v_param2_upper := upper(v_param2);
    v_param3_upper := upper(v_param3);
    v_param4_upper := upper(v_param4);
    v_param5_upper := upper(v_param5);

    . . .
end;
```

I do have no idea how the case of strings would result in recursive calls, however.

Answer (score 0):

by using directly upper/lower function on variable you can achieve this:-

```
procedure Name (
   v_Param1 in number,
   v_Param2 IN varchar2,
   v_Para3 IN VARCHAr2,
   v_Param4 IN VARCHAr2,
   v_MID IN VARCHAr2)
as BEGIN
   v_Param2 := upper(v_Param2);
   v_Para3 := upper(v_Para3);
   v_Param4 := upper(v_Param4);
   v_MID := upper(v_MID);
......
END;
```